# Stack Navigation inside Tab Navigation React Native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I need to use `Stack Navigation` inside `Tab Navigation`

[fileStructure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ufREjLPAdmcORxUK-f4QvETHNTNjmylU/view?usp=sharing)

[Main.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1olX8EZ6kVs2ExVco2DI-Fj7NmOwV5C1d/view?usp=sharing)

[Dashboard.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10daXHH7V-4dwsxs3if_4wz49a8-V_Jq3/view?usp=sharing)

**What I want to achieve** . I need something like that . if someone click on `<ActionButton.Item>` (the one with add item) it create a stack screen of `NewBill screen`

I have tried a lot of ways & things, watched tutorial, Youtube videos, blogs but nothing worked.

Can someone show me how can i add this `Stack Navigation` in my code??

**<ActionButton.item>** - [image: pic]

Comment: just add a `StackNavigator` inside the `Dashboard` where you'll have `Dashboard.js` and `NewBill.js`